# Справка комментария еще на английском языке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии

Когда вы нажимаете «справка» при публикации комментария, текст еще на английском языке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я постоянно натыкаюсь на эту проблему, на мете пишут про это, но пока что-то ничего не меняется. Почему? Вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: @VladSpirin, наш переводчик пытается выяснить на метамете, что, собственно, произошло: «[Already translated strings have lost their translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306091/357761)», «[Translations are not used from Transifex for localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306244/357761)». Ответа от команды разработчиков ещё нет. Единственное, что пока известно — в базе переводов последовательно и массово слетают идентификаторы, и это касается всех локализованных SO-сайтов.

Comment: @Arhad есть [подготовка к ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306244/translations-are-not-used-from-transifex-for-localized-sites#comment995612_306244) в виде комментария.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод слетел из-за замены захардкоженной ссылки `http://example.com` на переменную `$link$`. Теперь перевод поправлен. Появится на сайте после обновления базы и пересборки движка. До новых встреч на MSE :)

Comment: `замены захардкоженной ссылки http://example.com на переменную $link$` — но зачем? Это же не нажимаемая ссылка, а образец разметки. Да и имя домена по RFC, то есть менять там нечего.

Comment: @Arhad а вдруг это приведёт к филанизию на каком-либо языке, как pajero или жигули?! Но вообще, вопрос не по адресу. Задайте на MSE, если хотите какое-то прояснение получить.